# Which datetime format to use SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a date as a varchar in the form

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM
```

e.g.

```
16/3/2012 4:39:26 PM
```

I can't see a valid format option for `CONVERT()` in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Am I missing something or will I have to reformat the varchar field first?

Edit:

Corrected the format, sorry about that

Comment: @AaronBertrand - That would be hextember.

Comment: @MattWhitfield I'll have to put that on my calendar.

Comment: OK, so it looks like a previous UPDATE to convert Greek letters into AM/PM was the problem. Thanks for the answers but I should have looked into the problem a bit more

Comment: @MattWhitfield I think you'l find that the names of months don't match their numbers (October = 10, December = 12) so 16 would be quaddecember. Sorry to be pedantic :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you get your story straight, you'll want one of these:

```
-- if you really meant dd/mm/yyyy then:

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '16/3/2012 4:39:26 PM', 103);

-- if you really meant mm/dd/yyyy then:

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/16/2012 4:39:26 PM', 101);
```

But agreed with Madhivanan. Don't store dates using the wrong data type, and if you must, use an unambiguous format!

Answer (score 4):

1. Always use proper `DATETIME` datatype to store dates
2. `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` are unambiguous date formats

For more information, refer this

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10898/understanding-datetime-column-part-ii.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an import from a file I have no control over. Otherwise I would be making sure to use an unambiguous format

Answer (score -3):

This will work.

```
DECLARE @dt varchar(100)='2012/3/16 4:39:26 PM'
select convert(datetime,@dt,101)
```

Comment: use 103 as option in convert function