# How to specify a SQL fixed day to work in all countries/languages

Tags: sql-server, date

I would like to run a SQL Insert that contains a fixed date. But it needs to work in all countries irrespective of regional settings and languages.

So, I was hoping this will work:

```
INSERT INTO MyDate (TheDate)
VALUES ('10-JAN-2021')
```

It works well, but only in some countries/languages. In Japan/China it gives an error that it can't parse the string to a date.

What is a better generic solution for hard coded dates?

Comment: Don't use localized date formats. Either use strongly typed date parameters or the ISO8601 format (ie 'YYYY-MM-DD') or the unseparated format 'YYYYMMDD'). You may run into trouble even with the ISO format if you use the old `datetime` type instead of `datetime2`

Comment: `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` are the way to go. They are unambiguous regardless of data type and language.

Comment: If you only want to store dates in `TheDate` use the `date` type instead of `datetime2` and certainly not `datetime`. This makes querying for all rows in a specific date a *lot* easier - no need to truncate the time part with leads to inefficient execution plans

Comment: Why don't you just include the date format of your hard-coded value ?. Example : `INSERT INTO MyDate (TheDate) VALUES (CONVERT(DATE,'2021-01-10',23))`   (23 is the ISO8061 yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which datetime format to use SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668069/which-datetime-format-to-use-sql-server) Specifically this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668138/14868997

Comment: Also see https://madhivanan.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/best-practices-use-unambiguous-date-formats/